# Offsetting div, while using 960

Tags: css, html, png

I am trying to offset a div which holds a transpanrent PNG with a logo. Similar to this sites use of such style. http://axiswake.com/

I assume I can not offset the div past the wrapper of 960. I am using the 960 grid system

I suppose I could make a div outsite of the main wrapper and offset from the center? I just need it to align properly in the end.

I am a noob to all of this.

Just to clarify, lets say I have my 960 wrapper, I want this .png contained in the div i am trying to offset to be lets say 200px to the left of the wrappers left border.

Thank you

Comment: "I assume I can not offset the div past the wrapper of 960" = why? You could try negative margins. Position: relative. Position: absolute. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just use negative margin, like this:

```
.logo {
  margin: 0 0 0 -200px;
}
```